# Why does JQuery offset change when I slide the view on my Android?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Update: I can't make this break on jsfiddle, but sometimes it breaks on my standalone site, and sometimes it doesn't.  I really wish I could remove this question -- sorry for lack of clarity.  Every time I think I have a simple demo case ironed out, later testing shows that offset is working fine for that case.**

**Later Update: now I know -- offset() breaks on Samsung if there is any zooming/scaling.  Drat.  I'd still love any ideas for workarounds.**

I am running into a big difference between JQuery's offset method when run on my Android Samsung 5 (Chrome browser) as compared to a number of other setups (iPad with Safari, Macbook Pro with Chrome, Windows 10 with Chrome).  In the latter three cases, offset().left does not change when I slide (iPad) or scroll (laptop and desktop).  It gives the distance from the document's left side to the left side of my element.  Good -- that's what i need.

But then if I slide the page left on my Samsung, the offset().left value increases by the amount of the slide.  The element has not changed it's location at all relative to the document!

I tried to make you an example (see code below) but when I posted it at  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pinkushn/LoLep6rs/), then tested it on my phone, IT WORKED.  That is, the offset().left performed as expected.  However, when I put the exact same code into its own page at my [my site](http://gmmapp.com/Mobile/ab.html), the Android/Samsung once again supplied the wrong offset.

If you go to the site shown above on a Samsung 5, then click on the blue div, you will see that its offset().left is 8 pixels.  If you then do some sliding/scrolling so that the blue div goes off the left side of the screen, then click on the blue div, you should still see that offset().left is 8 pixels.  However, my Android gives a steadily increasing value for offset the more I slide.  Can anyone explain?  And for a bonus, any ideas for a universal remedy?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .bulky {width:2000px; height:150px; background-color:blue;}
    .smaller {width:200px; height:150px;background-color:orange;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="bulky"></div>
    <div class="smaller"></div>
</body>
<script>
    $(".bulky").click(function() {
        alert("offset left: " + $(".bulky").offset().left);
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: How is going if you run it into a webview?

Comment: I haven't tried a webview.

Comment: What was wrong?

Comment: Wish I knew.  Seems like I can't get it to break anymore except in my rather complicated full-blown app.  But in a way, that's good news: I'll just keep building the demo till I find the issue.  Hopefully.

Comment: Try to add `setTimeout` to your testcase and replace `alert` with `console` - it might be the delay of redrawing the canvas, which might be handled differently between individual devices.

Comment: Thanks, @canis: unfortunately, no change.

Comment: Is the issue perhaps related to the auto-hiding of the address bar in the browser? This is one of the gigantic pains in the virtual a** when working with anything viewport related.

Comment: I'm focusing purely on horizontal right now, @Bram, so I don't think so.

Answer (score -1):

Does adding this to the head tag fix it?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
```

I'm not sure it will work but I have to post it as a answer cause dnt looks good in a comment .So you welcome do downvote I'm just trying to help :)

Comment: No, thanks.  I deliberately left off viewport issues to focus the issue on jQuery.offset().  But don't worry, I can't downvote, not enough Stack points.

Comment: I have no other ideas right now ,but I'm curious how it works in a android webview